# Plain C loading a C# dll

Tags: c++, c

I have a third party app that is a C# dll and I am trying to make calls to it from a plain C code. I have been able to create a C++ executable and call a C# dll with info I found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736). But I'm looking for a plain C, has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COM works just fine in plain C.  Your example should work almost exactly like it is, however you will have to use C syntax for calling a function associated with an object.  Change

```
pICalc->Add(5, 10, &lResult);
```

to

```
pICalc->lpVtbl->Add(pICalc, 5, 10, &lResult); // no implicit this pointer, pass explicitly
```

For more examples, see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C#C